# Interpretation for the predicate formula

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Let the possible variable values be $ \Bbb U = \{true, false\} $. There are no predicates in the following formulae since the variable values already are boolean values. Give the truth value for each interpretation for the following formula:

$ \forall x \forall y: (x \land y) \leftrightarrow \lnot x $

I have no idea how to solve the given problem. Can anyone please help me? Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: I thought when there are quantifiers, we can't just use truth tables.

Comment: OK, thank you :D 
So, the same approach would be done if we had for example formula: $ \exists x \forall y (x \lor y) $ ?

Comment: In every interpretation with *finite* domain we may - in principle - write a table with all possible combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a propositional logic problem in disguise : the solution is simply the turth-table of the propositional formula : $(x∧y) ↔ ¬x$.

We can easily check that for $v(x) = v(y)= \text {true}$ the formula is evaluated to $\text {false}$.

Thus, it is not true that $\mathbb U \vDash ∀x \ ∀y \ ((x ∧ y) ↔ ¬x)$.

In the same way, we can check with $v(x)= \text {true}$ that $∃x∀y (x \lor y)$ is true in $\mathbb U$.